# Could not find main class HelloWorld

Tags: java

I installed Java 1.7.0 in the following folder `C:\Program Files\Java`.   My operating system is Windows XP(Version 2002) with Service pack 3.

The environment variables which I set are:

- **CLASSPATH** : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar;`
- **Path :** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;`
- **JAVA_HOME** : `C:\Program Files\Java;`

I have presented here the class names which are in my system.

Next I wrote a program, HelloWorld.java:

```
import java.io.*;

class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

When I am compiling using `javac HelloWorld.java` it is compiling fine.

But after I issue `java HelloWorld` I am encountering the below error:

```
Error: Could not find main class HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:198)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:299)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:288)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:287)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:422)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:355)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:195)
```

After a bit of searching around, I found that may be something wrong in the environment variable. I tried to play with that but no luck.

I even RESTARTED the machine and then again I tried to run but with same fate.

Comment: just a reminder: jdk 7 is not officially stable yet. So if there's something funny always keep in mind that you might want to recompile with jdk 6.

Comment: Instead of using an unreleased version of Java 7, download and use JDK 6 here: http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

Comment: ... but this is not a jdk 7 problem.

Comment: AFAIK jdk 7 is official, are you confusing with 8?

Comment: remove CLASSPATH environment variable. and then try

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are not setting a classpath that includes your compiled class! `java` can't find any classes if you don't tell it where to look.

```
java -cp [compiler outpur dir] HelloWorld
```

Incidentally you do not need to set CLASSPATH the way you have done.

Answer (score 35):

Tell it where to look for you class: it's in ".", which is the current directory:

```
java -classpath . HelloWorld
```

No need to set `JAVA_HOME` or `CLASSPATH` in this case

Comment: Wow, magic! I am messing around with no results, but this worked immediately! Thank you very much!

Comment: @unbeli I had the same problem, and amazingly this solved it. I'm just curious. I'm watching Lynda.com Java tutorial and I do exactly same thing as him, his works (He types in only java HelloWorld), mine not (I had this problem). Why is this so? What have he done so not to have to type "." Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Just remove your "classpath" from you environment variable. Then try running:

```
java HelloWorld
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

Java is not finding where your compiled class file (HelloWorld.class) is. It uses the directories and JAR-files in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable for searching if no `-cp` or `-classpath` option is given when running java.exe.

You don't need the rt.jar in the `CLASSPATH`, these was only needed for older versions of Java. You can leave it undefined and the current working directory will be used, or just add `.` (a single point), separated by ';', to the `CLASSPATH` variable to indicate the current directory:

**CLASSPATH:** `.;C:\...\some.jar`

Alternatively you can use the `-cp` or `-classpath` option:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

And, as Andreas wrote, `JAVA_HOME` is not needed by Java, just for some third-party tools like ant (but should point to the correct location).

Answer (score 4):

You either want to add "." to your CLASSPATH to specify the current directory, or add it manually at run time the way unbeli suggested.

Answer (score 2):

put .; at classpath value in beginning..it will start working...it happens because it searches the class file in classpath which is mentioned in path variable.

Answer (score 1):

`JAVA_HOME` is not necessary if you start java and javac from the command line. But `JAVA_HOME` should point to the real jdk directory, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0` in your case.

I'd never use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable outside of build scripts, especially not global defined. The `-cp` flag is better. But in your case, as you do not need additional libraries (`rt.jar`doesn't count), you won't need a classpath declaration. A missing `-cp` is equivalent to a `-cp .` and that's what you need here)

<strike>The `HelloWorld` class needs to be declared as `public`. This actually may be the cause for your problems.</strike> (I was pretty sure, that a source file needs one public class... or was it one public class *at most* ?)

Comment: `HelloWorld` not being public does not cause this problem. Other than that, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Perhaps, the problem is that you have compiled and executed the class with different Java versions.

Make sure **the version of the compiler is the same as the command "java"**:

```
javac -version

java -version
```

In Linux, use

**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

to change the version of Java.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same problem....

Actually this problem is raised due to the fact that your program `.class` files are not saved in that directory. Remove your CLASSPATH from your environment variable (you do no need to set classpath for simple Java programs) and reopen cmd prompt, then compile and execute.

If you observe carefully your `.class` file will save in the same location. (I am not an expert, I am also basic programer if there is any mistake in my sentences please ignore it :-))

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you had done all setup properly but there might be one area where it might be causing problem

Check the value of your "CLASSPATH" variable and make sure at the end you kept **;.**

Note: 
**;** is for end separator
**.** is for including existing path at the end