# Unable to run java program using command prompt

Tags: java

How I can run java program using command prompt? I already run my program using command prompt but i get this error `Could not find or load main class ReadWriteTextFile`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java problem: Could not find main class HelloWorld](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005433/java-problem-could-not-find-main-class-helloworld)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a few conditions on running a java class:

- First of all, the file you want to run should have a public class, with the same name as the file. For instance, `Test.java` would contain the `Test` class.
- The public class should have a main method. This is a static method. It's arguments are the command line arguments passed. It's signature must be `public static void main(String[] args)`.

As an example class you can call from the command line:

```
public class ReadWriteTextFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readWriteTextFile();
    }
    public static void readWriteTextFile() {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

If saved in the file `ReadWriteTextFile.java`, you can compile and call it like this:

```
$ javac ReadWriteTextFile.java
$ java ReadWriteTextFile
$
```

Seen from the error message you get, your file is probably called `ReadWriteTextFile`, but you haven't got a public ReadWriteTextFile class with a `main` method in it.

Comment: I already have public class same name as the file. This is my public class in my program -  public class ReadWriteTextFile
{

 private static void ReadWriteTextFile()

Comment: And do you have the `main` method? That the method called from the command line. It should be something like `public static void main(String[] args) { ReadWriteTextFile(); }`

Comment: When I run $ javac ReadRiteTextFile.java I get this error -  $ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: I'm sorry, you shouldn't type the $. It indicates the start of a new command. You should type `javac ReadWriteTextFile.java` to compile, and `java ReadWriteTextFile` in order.

Answer (score 0):

Check your entry point specification in your manifest as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html): 
You should set an entry like this one:
`Main-Class: YourPackage.ReadWriteTextFile`
Maybe the package path is missing? I got myself this kind of issue when launching jar files... I hope this helps.