# Couldnt find the main class

Tags: java

Well, i complile my program using this command in Ubuntu

```
javac -classpath .:/home/ss/lucene-4.0.0/core/lucene-core-4.0.0.jar:/home/ss/lucene-4.0.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.0.0.jar:/home/ss/lucene-4.0.0/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.0.jar:/home/ss/lo.jar:/home/neetish/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar kel.java
```

It compiles.

And I run using

```
  java -classpath .:/home/ss/lucene-4.0.0/core/lucene-core-4.0.0.jar:/home/ss/lucene-4.0.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.0.0.jar:/home/ss/lucene-4.0.0/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.0.jar:/home/ss/lo.jar:/home/ss/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar kel.java
```

and i Get

```
Could not find or load main class kel.java
```

can anyone help me plz

Comment: do `java -cp ... kel` also do you have `main()`  in your class ?

Comment: @code: If your problem has been resolved, accept an answer and move on.

Comment: @Neetz why are you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a main() method in kel.java and if it is successfully compile then

you can run it using following command.

```
java -classpath kel
```

in your case you are trying to run kel.java. That is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Even though your source file's name kel.java, your class' name is just `kel`

You have to start your program with

```
java -cp ... kel
```

You should not add any suffix to the class name.

Comment: Note that this only applies when *running* the program. When *compiling*, in contrast, it is necessary to include the .java extension.

Comment: @OP: Also make sure that the ``classpath`` is pointed to the directory where the compiled files are put. You might [find this useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005433/java-problem-could-not-find-main-class-helloworld?rq=1)

Comment: @T-Bull Comiling is done with `javac` and the original poster had no problem with compiling but with running, which is done by the command `java` as I wroe.

Comment: @UwePlonus: I know. Just pointed that out to already explain the next source of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

After compilation, you can run by `java kel`.
Simply remove the .class from you compiled file.

Answer (score 0):

After compilation, just give class name, instead kel.java. Just mention kel.