# java Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, runtime-error, fedora

Im using fedora 19.
Content of HelloWorld.java :

```
    class HelloWorld {
        public static void main( String args[] ) {
            System.out.println( "Hello World!!" );
        }
    }
```

I can successfully compile it using

> javac HelloWorld.java

But i cannot run it using

> java HelloWorld

It gives the following error

> Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

But i can run it using

> sudo java HelloWorld

What am I missing here???

Comment: Do you have execute permission for `java` under your user?

Comment: Did you accidently compile as the super user?

Comment: @MadProgrammer How can i check that?

Comment: Maybe you can read this ? It look similar to your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096016/java-cant-find-main-class

Comment: @PP I have already given that a try. It still wont work.

Comment: don't you use an IDE? eclipse , something?

Answer (score 9):

You are not setting a classpath that includes your compiled class! `java` can't find any classes if you don't tell it where to look.

Try `java -cp . HelloWorld`

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005472/12860)

Not sure why it works with sudo though. My[*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbjorn-ravn-andersen) guess would be, that the CLASSPATH is set for the root user and not for the current user.

Comment: It works with this... Why do i have to write -cp? What does it mean?

Comment: Is this a requirement for linux as it works just find on Windows?

Comment: cp stands for ClassPath, which are all the paths/folders where classes can be found.  the dot operator means "local directory"

Comment: -cp parameter tells the runtime to search for class files in the given directories, which in your case is the present directory. Hence the argument -cp = ClassPath

Comment: Check for a CLASSPATH environnemnt variable with `export`.

Comment: But i never used that before in ubuntu. is there a way to set it to use the default path which is the current directory? Any idea why it runs with the sudo command

Comment: Did you update your java recently? Sometimes changes (especially security fixes) are not backward compatible.

Comment: @Burkhard - If he is running a Java application from the command line, his code is not sandboxed.  It is extremely unlikely that a Java security fix will break things in that case.  (Applets and Webstart applications are a different matter ... but irrelevant to the OP's use-case.)

Comment: Any idea why I don't have to add the -cp option? I can just `java classname` and it works for me. I also use fedora and I don't have to add the -cp option.

Comment: This is a requirement on Windows, as well.  Thanks, @Burkhard

Answer (score 4):

Dear Pranav Chugh,

```
1- cmd - go the directory of located java file
```

**run the following on cmd**

```
2- javac HelloWorld.java 
3- java HelloWorld             ---- not not add .class
```

here you will get the result

Answer (score 0):

This is rather bizarre.  It *seems* like the problem is that when you run `java` as a non-privileged user it cannot find or read the ".class" file.  But when run as "root", you can.

This suggests that you have somehow managed to create the "HelloWorld.class" file with the wrong owner and/or the wrong permissions.

Check the permissions by running `ls -l HelloWorld.class`.  The owner should be your user account (not "root") and you need user read permission on the file.

Here are a couple of other possible explanations:

- The `java` command you are running might not be what you think it is.  Check what `which java` says when you run it as yourself.  Check that it is the "real" `java` executable and not some script or something in the current directory or some other directory that won't be on the root / sudo `$PATH`.
- You might have set your `CLASSPATH` environment variable such that the current directory (where "HelloWorld.class" is ... I assume) is not on the classpath.  But when you `sudo java`, the `java` command is running with an environment in which `$CLASSPATH` is not set.  In that case, if there is no `-cp` argument, you will get a default classpath consisting of just `"."`; i.e. the current directory.

---

If the problem turns out to be the CLASSPATH environment variable, I recommend that you *unset* it ... and edit your shell's "rc" files to unset it there too.

Instead, use the '-cp' command on the `java` command, `javac` command and so on ... and switch to either Ant or Maven or an IDE for building and running code.  (Or you could write some little wrapper scripts as application launchers.)

Don't depends on the CLASSPATH environment variable.  It is liable to give you nasty surprises, especially if you are switching between coding projects.  (Certainly don't depend on it in your production environment!)

Comment: How can i unset the classpath variable

Comment: Use the `unset` shell command.  Or don't set or `export` it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue just trying to run HelloWorld on Mac 10.7.5.  I compiled the HelloWorld.java file without issue with javac.  I then tried to run "java HelloWorld" and got the same error: "Could not find or load main class"

It was only after I changed the directory (cd) in the Mac Terminal to the directory containing the .class file that I was able to run the program.

HTH,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem before. Maybe you made the same mistake. 
***My mistake was using "cd" to go inside the package directory rather than the directory right above it.*** 
For example wenn the directory right above are called "Hello", you can run it by typing:     java Hello/HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your CLASSPATH setting is wrong. 
check your CLASSPATH and make sure that is :

```
CLASSPATH="YourJavaHome/lib:."
```

be attention there is a ':.' in the end of the sentence!
after that run

```
source /etc/environment
```

and it should be work!

Comment: where can I find CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 0):

go to parent folder and run, it works for me

```
C:\Users\WINDOWS 8\workspace\Demo\target\classes\dto>cd ..

C:\Users\WINDOWS 8\workspace\Demo\target\classes>java dto.HelloHP
```