# Could not find main class Java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have two classes `Pair.java` and `Users.java` where `Users.java` has the main program. Both these java files are under the package `userdetails`.

In unix,
I compiled it using the command

```
javac -d . -classpath avro-1.7.5.jar:lib/*:jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:lib/* Pair.java Users.java
```

the class are under the folder userdetails.
I tried to run using the command

```
java  -classpath avro-1.7.5.jar:lib/*:jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:lib/* userdetails.Users
```

I'm getting error

> Could not find main class userdetails.Users

Kindly help me.

source code :-

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader; 
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter; 
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader; 
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter; 
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader; 
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter; 
import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
public class Users {
 public void createUser() {
            userdetails.Pair datum = new userdetails.Pair(new Utf8("L"), new Utf8("R"));
            DatumWriter writer = new SpecificDatumWriter();
            DataFileWriter fileWriter = new DataFileWriter(writer);



            try {
                    fileWriter.create(datum.getSchema(), new File("users.avro"));
                    fileWriter.append(datum);
                    System.out.println(datum);
                    fileWriter.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }         }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Users user = new Users();
            user.createUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: post some code here specially your main method

Comment: import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader;
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;                                  public class Users {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
                Users user = new Users();
                user.createUser();
        }
}

Comment: now please edit your question and put the remaining part of your code there

Comment: Your code doesnt have a package statement at the top

Comment: added and ran it .. still the same issue

Comment: a little indentation wouldn't hurt

Comment: Read this stackoverflow question [could not find main][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005433/java-problem-could-not-find-main-class-helloworld

Answer (score 2):

When you specify a classpath, the current working directory is not automatically contained any more, so you must add it to the classpath:

```
java  -classpath avro-1.7.5.jar:lib/*:jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:lib/*:. userdetails.Users
```

Answer (score 0):

You say both classes are under the package "userdetails", but there is no package declaration at the beginning of your source. Both `Pair.java` and `User.java` should begin with the line:

```
package userdetails;
```

Check out the [Java Packages Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)