# Error: Main method not found in class. can anybody will give me a proper solution for this error please

Tags: java

Error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class app, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

Code:

```
class app
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double accounts[];
        accounts=new double[100];
        accounts[2]=1225.33;
        System.out.println("Account 2 is overdue by $"+accounts[2]);
    }
}
```

I am using **EditPlus** to run and execute this program.

Comment: Could you paste your code

Comment: class app 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  double accounts[];
  accounts=new double[100];
  accounts[2]=1225.33;
  System.out.println("Account 2 is overdue by $"+accounts[2]);
 }
}

Comment: @sipramahalik I edited it (and formatted it) for you in the opening post.  Also, what IDE are you using?  How are you compiling it?  Is this an Android project by any chance?

Comment: You might try using a different IDE such as Eclipse and see if you are getting that same error message.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005433/java-problem-could-not-find-main-class-helloworld).  It's most likely your problem.  Something is probably wrong with how you set your class path

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think there is some problem with my EditPlus because its executing fine using Eclipse.

Comment: Make sure you didn't miss anything here then:  http://www-acad.sheridanc.on.ca/~jollymor/editplus.html

Comment: I am re installing my EditPlus again using the info you are provided thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a class you need the main method.  Add the main method to the class and put the code you are trying to execute inside the main method and it should execute.  Also post the code you do have so it's easier for us to understand what you are trying to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //code goes here
}
```

Comment: I have already written main method in my code but i don't know why this error showing again and again.

Comment: I am writing a very simple code if you wants to see it i can post it here.

Comment: class app 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  double accounts[];
  accounts=new double[100];
  accounts[2]=1225.33;
  System.out.println("Account 2 is overdue by $"+accounts[2]);
 }
}

Comment: Edit it into your opening post @sipramahalik

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code how are you executing eclipse, netbeans, command prompt...?

Comment: How are you compiling and executing the code?  Command Prompt? Because there is nothing wrong with your code have you tried compiling and running? Because that editor may be saying there is something wrong even though there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is either something broken about the tools you are using, or the process you are using.  (For example, you might have made a mistake with your classpath.)

At any rate, your program works for me, as demonstrated by the following:

```
[steve@newbox tmp]$ cat > app.java
class app
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double accounts[];
        accounts=new double[100];
        accounts[2]=1225.33;
        System.out.println("Account 2 is overdue by $"+accounts[2]);
    }
}


[steve@newbox tmp]$ javac app.java 
[steve@newbox tmp]$ java app
Account 2 is overdue by $1225.33
[steve@newbox tmp]$
```

For the record, this is with Java 8 tools ... and I haven't set the CLASS_PATH environment variable.  (Hence, `java` and `javac` will just be using the current directory as the classpath.)

---

The only other possibility I can think of is that your original code has a nasty homoglyph in (maybe) the `main` identifier, that causes the `java` command to not see the method.  There is a chance that StackOverflow will silently "fix" homographs in Questions and Answers.  (It certainly seems to "fix" dodgy control codes.)