# Could not find or load main class [location]

Tags: java, class, load, find

When I try to open a java file I get an error :

> could not find or load main class + location of the file

I'll give an example , let's say I have a file.java in my C:\Program Files\Folder.

When i'll try to open that file it'll say :

> Could not find or load main class C:\Program Files\Folder\File.java

I looked all around google and I found things about environmental variables , but I have already set my classpath and path.

MIGHT BE IMPORTANT : I use Jdk 1.8.0_25

Comment: Maybe these links will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005433/java-problem-could-not-find-main-class-helloworld

Comment: What does it mean "open java file". What are you exactly dowing?

Comment: Are you using the command 'java File.java' from the command prompt? does your File.java have a package declaration?

Comment: Should't you run .jar file, rather then .java?

Comment: by opening a java file I mean just double clicking a .java file.

Comment: and what do you mean  by a package declaration ?

Answer (score 0):

`.java` files are not meant to be launched with `java` command.

You should compile it first with `javac` that will produce a `.class` file then if it's a class with a `main` method you can use `java` command.

Since you seem completely lost I would suggest reading at least the java documentation and do a welcome tutorial.

Note that if as you stated in your other question (which should be closed now) that you want to run a game server, just download already compiled classes not the sources.